# Akka-Stream using Partition stage

Tags: akka-stream

I am trying to find an example that shows how to use, Akka Stream Partition capability. I am trying to optimize writing a Store. For that i would like to group item in a batch of my choosing and write them at once, however to make use of parallelism i would like to do it in parallel. Hence the batch and then the writing in the database would happen let say on 8 simultaneous threads.

I would be able to write 30 records as one update on 8 parallel threads.

Grouped or GroupedWithin are well documented and i have tried them with success. However, the only thing i see to do what i want to in parallel is actually a partitioning. I'd to partition randomly, i don't care about how it is partition. If there is facilities to like round-robin partitioner, i'd like to know as well.

But first and foremost how do I use partition. Do i have to build a GraphBuilder ?

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usage example of `Partition` can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/johanandren/c4e37ac655a53d256aaf301743a254dd).

If you're looking for random partitioning, the `Balance` stage is what you need. The docs provide an example [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/stream/stream-cookbook.html#balancing-jobs-to-a-fixed-pool-of-workers).

In both cases you need to make use of the GraphDSL, documented [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/stream/stream-graphs.html).